# XAML ScrollViewer's child bring into view event

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a `ScrollViewer`, at the top area, there is a video player, and a `ListView` below the media player.

While scrolling up and down, when the media player bring into view, it starts to play. When scroll down till the media player disappears, the media player pauses.

So, how to do it? Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [ScrollViewer.ViewChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.viewchanged) event to know the user scrolling and zooming the [ScrollViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer). But the [ScrollViewer.ViewChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.viewchanged) do not raise when the layout changing.

So we can use [LayoutUpdated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.layoutupdated) event to do it.

We can get some property from [ScrollViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer) just as HorizontalOffset and VerticalOffset.

We can get the coordinates of the top left corner of a control relative to the previous control.

```
        var top = control.TransformToVisual(StackPanel).TransformPoint(new Point());
```

And then we can judge whether the element can be seen by the user through the intersection of the rectangles.

```
        var controlBounds = new Rect(top, control.DesiredSize);

        var viewBounds = new Rect(new Point(ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset, ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset), new Size(ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth, ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight));

        if (RectIntersects(viewBounds, controlBounds))
        {

        }
```

[image]

We should write the RectIntersects the check two rectangles is intersectant.

```
    private static bool RectIntersects(Rect a, Rect b)
    {
        return !(b.Left > a.Right
            || b.Right < a.Left
            || b.Top > a.Bottom
            || b.Bottom < a.Top);
    }
```